# How do I set file permissions after moving files from one account to another using root username via FTP

Tags: wordpress, root, whm

I have a WHM for which I have root access. I've logged into the server via FTP and moved WordPress files from one acccount (dev) to a new account (live)

Now I get all sorts of errors when working in WordPress, specifically when trying to install or update plugins. All what I assume relate to the file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

if you have ssh access, run chown -R liveusername:livegroupname * from the web root of the live account.  This will recursively change ownership of all the files in the root folder and all subfolders.  The actual web root directory permissions should give you an insight as to what liveusername and livegroupname values should be.